# CSS not loaded with net::ERR_ABORTED 404 error

Tags: php, symfony

When I updated from Symfony 3.4 to 4.0 and displayed it in a browser, the following error appeared.
Symfony/assets are also installed,
I tried the code below but it didn't work.
Is there anything else you can think of?
**Directory**

```
src/
　└ Resources/
　　　　　　┝ public/css/style.css
           └ view/layout.html.twg
```

**Try Code**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{absolute_url(asset('css/style.css'))}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/style.css">
```

**Version**
Symfony 4.0.15
PHP 7.3
symfony/asset 4.0.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the css directory from within the Resources/public directory to inside the public/ directory in the project and the code below fixed the issue.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/style.css') }}">
```